# AVAssetWriter - Capturing video but no audio

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am making an app that records video. Up until now, I have been able to successfully record video and audio using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, however, I now have a need to edit the video frames in real time to overlay some data onto the video. I began the switch to `AVAssetWriter`.

After the switch, I am able to record video (with my overlays) just fine using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, however, `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` never calls the delegate method so my audio doesn't record.

This is how I set up my AVCaptureSession:

```
    fileprivate func setupCamera() {

        //Set queues
        queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myqueue", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: DispatchQueue.AutoreleaseFrequency.inherit, target: DispatchQueue.global())


        //The size of output video will be 720x1280
        print("Established AVCaptureSession")
        cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720

        //Setup your camera
        //Detect which type of camera should be used via `isUsingFrontFacingCamera`
        let videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice
        videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front)!
        print("Created AVCaptureDeviceInput: video")

        //Setup your microphone
        var audioDevice: AVCaptureDevice
        //audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)!
        audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInMicrophone, for: AVMediaType.audio, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)!
        print("Created AVCaptureDeviceInput: audio")


        do {
            cameraSession.beginConfiguration()
            cameraSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
            cameraSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = true


            // Add camera to your session
            let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
            if cameraSession.canAddInput(videoInput) {
                cameraSession.addInput(videoInput)
                print("Added AVCaptureDeviceInput: video")
            } else
            {
                print("Could not add VIDEO!!!")
            }

            // Add microphone to your session
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
            if cameraSession.canAddInput(audioInput) {
                cameraSession.addInput(audioInput)
                print("Added AVCaptureDeviceInput: audio")
            } else
            {
                print("Could not add MIC!!!")
            }


            //Define your video output
            videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [
                kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
            ]
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            if cameraSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
                videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
                cameraSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
                print("Added AVCaptureDataOutput: video")
            }


            //Define your audio output
            if cameraSession.canAddOutput(audioDataOutput) {
                audioDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
                cameraSession.addOutput(audioDataOutput)
                print("Added AVCaptureDataOutput: audio")
            }


            //Set up the AVAssetWriter (to write to file)
            do {
                videoWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: getURL()!, fileType: AVFileType.mp4)
                print("Setup AVAssetWriter")


                //Video Settings
                let videoSettings: [String : Any] = [
                    AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                    AVVideoWidthKey  : 720,
                    AVVideoHeightKey : 1280,
                    ]
                videoWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
                videoWriterVideoInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true;
                print("Setup AVAssetWriterInput: Video")
                if (videoWriter?.canAdd(videoWriterVideoInput!))!
                {
                    videoWriter?.add(videoWriterVideoInput!)
                    print("Added AVAssetWriterInput: Video")
                } else{
                    print("Could not add VideoWriterInput to VideoWriter")
                }


                // Add the audio input

                //Audio Settings
                let audioSettings : [String : Any] = [
                    AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                    AVSampleRateKey : 44100,
                    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 64000,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1
                ]
                videoWriterAudioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
                videoWriterAudioInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true;
                print("Setup AVAssetWriterInput: Audio")
                if (videoWriter?.canAdd(videoWriterAudioInput!))!
                {
                    videoWriter?.add(videoWriterAudioInput!)
                    print("Added AVAssetWriterInput: Audio")
                } else{
                    print("Could not add AudioWriterInput to VideoWriter")
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("ERROR")
                return
            }



            //PixelWriter
            videoWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterVideoInput!, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [
                kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 1280,
                kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 768,
                kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility as String: true,
                ])
            print("Created AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor")


            //Present the preview of video
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraSession)
            previewLayer.position = CGPoint.init(x: CGFloat(self.view.frame.width/2), y: CGFloat(self.view.frame.height/2))
            previewLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            print("Created AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer")

            //Don't forget start running your session
            //this doesn't mean start record!
            cameraSession.commitConfiguration()
            cameraSession.startRunning()
        }
        catch let error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Start recording:

```
    func startRecording()
    {
        print("Begin Recording...")
        let recordingClock = self.cameraSession.masterClock
        isRecording = true
        videoWriter?.startWriting()
        videoWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: CMClockGetTime(recordingClock!))


    }
```

Stop recording:

```
    func stopRecording()
    {

        if (videoWriter?.status.rawValue == 1) {
            videoWriterVideoInput?.markAsFinished()
            videoWriterAudioInput?.markAsFinished()
            print("video finished")
            print("audio finished")
        }else{
            print("not writing")
        }

        self.videoWriter?.finishWriting(){
            self.isRecording = false
            print("finished writing")
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                if self.videoWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.failed {
                    print("status: failed")
                }else if self.videoWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.completed{
                    print("status: completed")
                }else if self.videoWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.cancelled{
                    print("status: cancelled")
                }else{
                    print("status: unknown")
                }

                if let e=self.videoWriter?.error{
                    print("stop record error:", e)
                }
            }

        }

        print("Stop Recording!")

    }
```

And this is the delegate method, which gets called for video, but not for audio:

```
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        autoreleasepool {

                guard captureOutput != nil,
                    sampleBuffer != nil,
                    connection != nil,
                    CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) else { return }


                guard CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) else{
                    return
                }

                if (connection.isVideoOrientationSupported) {
                    connection.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
                } else
                {
                    return
                }

                if (connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported) {
                    //connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
                }


                if !self.isRecording
                {
                    return
                }


                var string = ""
                if let audio = self.videoWriterAudioInput
                {
                    if connection.audioChannels.count > 0
                    {
                        //EXECUTION NEVER REACHES HERE
                        if audio.isReadyForMoreMediaData
                        {
                            queue!.async() {
                                audio.append(sampleBuffer)
                            }
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
                print ("\(string)")


                if let camera = self.videoWriterVideoInput, camera.isReadyForMoreMediaData {

                    //This is getting called!!!

                    queue!.async() {
                        self.videoWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.append(self.imageToBuffer(from: image!)!, withPresentationTime: timestamp)


                    }




                }
        }//End autoreleasepool


    }




}
```

I am sure the problem does not lie with my devices or inputs, as I was able to successfully record video and audio using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. I have also read other relevant posts with no luck:

[Corrupt video capturing audio and video using AVAssetWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959376/corrupt-video-capturing-audio-and-video-using-avassetwriter)

[VAssetWriter audio with video together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419257/avassetwriter-audio-with-video-together)

Comment: Two different queues? Why though?

Comment: I suppose because the rate at which video and audio is being processed may differ, and you wouldn't want to block one for the other as you may encounter syncing issues? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripped my hair out for days on this. My mistake was simple - The delegate method was being called, but was being returned BEFORE I reached the audio statements. These were the culprits which needed to be moved to after the audio processing portion of my code:

```
            if (connection.isVideoOrientationSupported) {
                connection.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
            } else
            {
                return
            }

            if (connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported) {
                //connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
            }
```

Comment: `self.videoWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.append(self.imageToBuffer(from: image!)!, withPresentationTime: timestamp)` where is this image and timestamp come from ?